# Django app deployment to azure web sites not working

Tags: django, visual-studio, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have created an azure website and a django app with visual studio 2012.

I have downloaded the publish credentials from the azure website and tried to publish my django app from visual studio. The problem is that I always get the following message:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

Unfortunately, I don't get further information (even though I have debug=TRUE in my settings
.

I've tried also deploying from git, but I get exactly the same error.

Any hint on this is kinldly welcome.

Comment: check the error logs. They would have some more info